# C expandable array

Tags: c, arrays, expandable

I'm trying to create an expandable (indexed) array in C for String Elements, similar to say an `ArrayList<String>` in Java.

I googled around and found an implementation of an indexed expandable C-array and I was wondering if someone could help me adjust this for strings.

Note - I don't mind imposing a maximum length for the strings

Here is the code -

http://happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try it first and ask questions if you get stuck?

Comment: Your question is not bad. But it's not specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList's in Java are complex data structures based on object oriented programming, while arrays in C programming language are simply indexed `chains` of allocated memory of certain lengths.

The only way to access an element in C programming language array is to give it's index, which is used to compute the `address` of variable in this array you wish to access.

example:

If character[11] is an array of `char`, each char variable takes 1 byte, you wish to access 5th element of array `characters`, the address of this element will be compute like that: 5*1+(address of the first element).

If you wish to use more complex data structures in C programming language you will have to implement it. Here is a good place to start:

[Arraylist in C not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732856/arraylist-in-c)